# How do I use GitHub and Git to create a branch the correct way

Tags: git, github

Solo dev who is finally decided to use git and github instead of multiple versions on my hard drive.

I have created an initial master branch that I uploaded the current state of my project to.

I am now going to add a new feature to this project and after reading around I am sure that it is good to add new features to a new branch in github.

So I created a new branch in github.

But on my local machine I already have git that pushed to the master branch on the initial commit.

So now do I have to the clone the 2nd branch from github to my local machine or do I just keep developing as usual and only switch to the 2nd branch when I am ready to push the changes to github.

It's kind of simple stuff but just confusing as what to do and how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest that you read [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) for a deeper understanding of how git works. Chapters 2 and 3 are pretty much all you need for day-to-day work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Git and GitHub together, there are often multiple correct ways to accomplish a task.

However, the typical way this is accomplished is to create a branch locally (let's call it 'test'), and set it to track an origin branch.

```
$ git checkout -b test
Switched to a new branch 'test'
$ git push --set-upstream origin test                                                                                                                                                                           
 * [new branch]      test -> test
Branch 'test' set up to track remote branch 'test' from 'origin' by rebasing.
```

Do your work on `test`, periodically pushing it to GitHub. When finished, merge the branch into `master` at the command line, or open a pull request on GitHub and merge it there.

You don't need to create a branch in GitHub to do work on your own local branch.

Comment: Thank you so are you saying that I didn't need to create the branch in the remote github, just do it on my local machine

Comment: @UncleVector Yes. Once you get the hang of working with branches on your local machine, then you can learn how to get branches from a remote repo, like GitHub.